# Drawing path on maps in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ios5, mapkit, xcode4.3

I have a code in which i want to show the path between two points on the map. The problem is that it is showing the correct route along with the displacement of the points i.e it is joining the starting and ending points also.

But the code works correctly if instead of using loops I do it w/o loops. Is it something like CGContextCloseGraph() calls automatically in loops??

Please help me out. This is my code.

```
     - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
     {

     if(!self.hidden && nil != self.points && self.points.count > 0)
     {
       CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 

       if(nil == self.lineColor)
        self.lineColor = [UIColor blueColor];

       CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.lineColor.CGColor);
       CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);


       CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

               // This Loop doesnt works..

       for(int i = 0; i < self.points.count; i++)
       {
           CLLocation* location = [self.points objectAtIndex:i];
             CGPoint point = [_mapView convertCoordinate:location.coordinate toPointToView:self];


        if(i == 0)
        {
            // move to the first point
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
        }
        else
        {
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
        }
        }
               // This works..

              /*CLLocation* location = [self.points objectAtIndex:0];
              CGPoint point = [_mapView convertCoordinate:location.coordinate toPointToView:self];

            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);

            location = [self.points objectAtIndex:1];
            point = [_mapView convertCoordinate:location.coordinate toPointToView:self];
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);

           location = [self.points objectAtIndex:2];
           point = [_mapView convertCoordinate:location.coordinate toPointToView:self];
           CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
           location = [self.points objectAtIndex:3];
           point = [_mapView convertCoordinate:location.coordinate toPointToView:self];
           CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
           location = [self.points objectAtIndex:4];
           point = [_mapView convertCoordinate:location.coordinate toPointToView:self];
           CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
           location = [self.points objectAtIndex:5];
           point = [_mapView convertCoordinate:location.coordinate toPointToView:self];
           CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);*/


    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }
     }
```

Comment: Why not use the MKMapView overlay functionality and create a MKPolyline instead of drawing it manually?

Comment: Ohk...Thank you for your reply .
I will try that.
but is there any problem in this code???

Comment: What is self.points.count?  Make sure that the last coordinate in your points array is not the same as the first coordinate.

Comment: No I have already checked that.

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
I solved the problem , Actually I was traversing the data twice by mistake.